# Excel: how to copy individual columns with varying length into a new tab?

Tags: excel, vba

I am yet another newbie in macro writing... Here is what I am trying to do:

Copy certain columns from one sheet into another sheet and the length or rows can vary. Seems simple right? Yet I can't seem to get it.

```
Dim RowS01Max As Integer
Dim Sheet1Data() As Variant

With Sheets("sheet1")
  RowS01Max = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
  Sheet1Data = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(RowS01Max, 1)).Value
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
  .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(RowS01Max, 5)).Value = Sheet1Data
End With
```

So this works if I only want to copy one column ("A"), how do I expand the range, I am sure it is an easy fix?

Any hints are appreciated.

Cheers

Sandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helpful property of an Excel worksheet is `UsedRange`: this returns a VBA range object representing the area of the specified worksheet which has data in it. It's also handy to know about a sheet's VBA codename which is explained quite clearly in [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx).
With that in mind we can calculate a range representing the used cells in a given column (or columns) using the `Intersect` function and then copy it to our chosen destination.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Sheet1.Usedrange, Sheet1.Range("A:A"))

rng.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("B5")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is a piece of my code using some variables. I usually count how many rows i have in order to copy only until that row size.

I have something like this:

```
Set Compiled = Sheets("Compiled Sheet")
Set Cycle = Sheets("Cycle Sheet")

countNum = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) ' Counts how many rows you have

CompileHeader = Compiled.Range("CD1").Value  ' Copies header title.

Compiled.Range("CD2:CD" & countNum).Value = Cycle.Range(ColumnLetter & "2:" & ColumnLetter & countNum).Value
```

So in the above code i am copying column CD (i know, a lot of columns in my project) into the "Cycle Sheet" set as "Cycle." Its nice to set the sheets to not have to go down and rename all your code later since this tends to be a dynamic value.